# C# custom bindingsource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

My scenario is an asp.net web api 2 server and a winforms client.

I have an entity (eg. customer) and one of its properties is 'AddressId' which is the id on the address record in the addresses entity. Entities are in the web api project.

I also have a custom control in the winforms project that has a number of textboxes for the address (eg. street, house, city, postcode, etc). I have also defined all the data sources in my client.

Now, when I retrieve a customer object, I'm only retrieved the addressid. What is the correctly way to bind the address to the custom control? Should I retrieve a flattened customer object or make multiple calls to the api to retrieve additional details such as the address fields?

Comment: Sounds like you need an Address object in your Customer as well as the AddressId. Then you can bind your customer.Adress to the ui.

Comment: @artm looking at `I have also defined all the data sources in my client` The OP would have considered having Customer entity on client side being windows form

Comment: @Ivan so how are you now getting the AddressId? If I am not wrong, its a web api call and then when you retrieve `Customer` object, you have the `AddressId`?

Comment: @LearningNeverStops yes I have the id, but I would like to display the the address details in the address custom control and keep the addressId in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your comment, I would suggest something like this:

In you web app (asp.net part):

Firstly, create a Customer class that has a composition of Address class.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID;
    public string CustomerName;
    public uint CustomerPhoneNo;
    public Address CustomerAddress; //The address field here for every customer
}

public class Address
{
    public string Street;
    public string House;
    public string City;
    public string Postcode;
}
```

Secondly, how to get this in your client?

1. Ensure you have a `CustomerID` and then when you query from your Windows form (client), pass the ID, which the web api should return the object of `Customer`.
2. In your client side, you should ensure that you have the same Entity structure. (Customer Class)

After all this, populate your windows form with the `CustomerAddress` field, which further has `City`, `Street`, `House` and `Postcode`.

**Update:**

In your windows form, consider a control, `addressUserControl`, which have different textbox's, then, you need to have the `Customer` Entity replica in windows form and use as follows:

Say, `addressUserControl_load` event, add the values of the respective items:

```
//customer is an object of Customer
StreetTextBox.Text = customer.CustomerAddress.Street;
HouseTextBox.Text = customer.CustomerAddress.House;
CityTextBox.Text = customer.CustomerAddress.City;
PostTextBox.Text = customer.CustomerAddress.Postcode;
```

Now, here is what I would recommend, move all your `Entities` (like Customer class) into a library project. Use the same Entities library for both your asp.net and windows form projects. Ensuring you have same object to create and retrieve.

Comment: So the bindingsource property should be CustomerAddress instead of CustomerAddressId. How can the custom control read the Address properties when setting its bindingsource? Is there an event?

Comment: Yes the BindingSource can be CustomerAddress. How is your custom control defined? What all are present in that control? Based on that U can extract the data from the CustomerAddress and fill the control.

Comment: The custom control simply has 4 or 5 textboxes that represent the fields in the Address entity. When setting the bindingsource, how are the address properties placed in the textboxes? Is there an event?

Comment: There is no direct event which will help u to do it automatically. I will update the answer, for such control.

Comment: this is similar to what I'm. But I would like to go a step further and use an address bindingsource in the user control.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono, okay but then the context will be wrong if you single out just the `address`, because it is a `has-a` relation with `Customer`. You can write just an address binding source, but then at what cost of defining: `An Address has a Customer` !.